# jQuery save context onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway to bind an click listener on a child of an element, while still pointing the `$(this)` context to a fixed parent of that child?
For example so lets just say I had a page -

HTML:

```
<p><div data-important="idthatisneeded1" class="fixedClass">
<div id="dynamicallygeneratedfirstchild">
<div id="dynamicallygeneratedsecondchild">
<a class="clickabblelinkfromtheparent" href="#">Link1</a>
</div>
</div>
</div></p>
<p><div data-important="idthatisneeded2" class="fixedClass">
<div id="dynamicallygeneratedfirstchild">
<a class="clickabblelinkfromtheparent" href="#">Link2</a>
</div>
</div></p>
```

I want to grab the values of `data-important` from `.fixedClass` whenever `.clickabblelinkfromtheparent` is clicked, without using `.parent().parent()` or `.parent()` since they're both unreliable -

JS:

```
$(".fixedClass .clickabblelinkfromtheparent").on("click",function(){alert($(this).parent().parent().data("important"));return false;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcdSw/

I've also tried:

```
$(".fixedClass .clickabblelinkfromtheparent").on("click",function(){alert($(this).context(".fixedClass").data("important"));return false;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcdSw/1/

```
$(".clickabblelinkfromtheparent", ".fixedClass").on("click",function(){alert($(this).data("important"));return false;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8a67/
and

```
$(".clickabblelinkfromtheparent", ".fixedClass").on("click",function(){alert($(this).context);return false;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8a67/1/

None of which seems to work.. So how exactly is this achievable with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying something like this? jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zKp3P/

```
$(function(){
  $('.clickabblelinkfromtheparent').on('click', function(){
    //$(this).closest('.fixedClass').data('important');
    alert($(this).closest('.fixedClass').data('important'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a much more simple approach to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clickabblelinkfromtheparent').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.fixedClass').data('important'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the first data-important attribute value of an ancestor in the DOM tree, you can tree something based on this snippet :

```
function searchDataInParentAxe($child, key) {
  var parent = $child.parent();
  return parent.data(key) || searchDataInParentAxe(parent, key);
}

$(".clickabblelinkfromtheparent").on("click", function () {
  alert(searchDataInParentAxe($(this), 'important'));
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zoom/2mhSQ/

Note that with this method you don't need the fixedClass anymore.